# What are hsfiles? Why use a ".hsfiles" extension instead of a regular ".hs"?

Tags: haskell, yesod

Reading [Yesod](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod)'s source code, I've encountered files with a ".hsfiles" extension. Example: [mongo.hsfiles](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/blob/c7d41f2395cd2fecb8f47756bb2eaea09e01f128/yesod-bin/hsfiles/mongo.hsfiles). What are them, why they were created and why use them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see [here](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/blob/931caaa2c01c4e3515f0d12f248ddc6bdfad5ccb/yesod-bin/Scaffolding/Scaffolder.hs) the relevant code:

```
backendBS :: Backend -> S.ByteString
backendBS Sqlite = $(embedFile "hsfiles/sqlite.hsfiles")
backendBS Postgresql = $(embedFile "hsfiles/postgres.hsfiles")
backendBS PostgresqlFay = $(embedFile "hsfiles/postgres-fay.hsfiles")
backendBS Mysql = $(embedFile "hsfiles/mysql.hsfiles")
backendBS MongoDB = $(embedFile "hsfiles/mongo.hsfiles")
backendBS Simple = $(embedFile "hsfiles/simple.hsfiles")
backendBS Minimal = $(embedFile "hsfiles/minimal.hsfiles")
```

So, it's used in their Scaffolding site to generate the defaults.

Comment: Thanks to your answer I've searched the what `ByteString`s are, and also what the `embedFile` function do (it embeds a file into the source code right?). However, I didn't understood what the `$` just before the parentheses does... I googled it, but I don't know if it is used to "splice", or if it is a splice, and in any case I don't know what a splice is. Could you answer me this?

Comment: @MarcusViníciusMonteiro That's a template haskell function. See the template haskell section in the second chapter: http://www.yesodweb.com/book/haskell